# What’s the etymology of “April”?

Tags: etymology

What is the meaning of the name *April*? Any ideas?

I have a friend who wants to know the meaning of her name.

Comment: Your title is too generic, I thought you were either asking for the etymology for the word, etymology or "name".

Answer (score 2):

**April**
c.1300, aueril, from Old French avril (11c.), from Latin (mensis) Aprilis "(month) of Venus," second month of the ancient Roman calendar, dedicated to the goddess Venus and perhaps based on Apru, **an Etruscan borrowing of Greek Aphrodite.** In English in Latin form from mid-12c. **Replaced Old English Eastermonað, which was similarly named for a fertility goddess.** Re-spelled in Middle English on Latin model (apprile first attested late 14c.).

Source: Etymonline

It origin seems to come from *Aphrodite* with reference to this fruitful period of the year.

Answer (score 1):

april means to open, like buds, in allusion to its being the season when trees and flowers begin to "open". 
hence it means to open like a flower or bud like in spring.

Comment: Connected with the Latin verb aper-ire meaning to open.

Comment: I'd actually like to see a reference for this. That is, other than whattonamemybaby.com and the like. A quick look into dictionaries suggests it has nothing to do with *aperire*, but was derived from the month, which *again* has nothing to do with *aperire*. I'd rather not have us spread folk etymology here.